# How to rename multiple files in same folder with same filename using batch scrpt?

Tags: windows, batch, script

i need small help, how to rename multiple files without touching their extension (in this case it winrar extension .r*) with batch script? When i try to rename it with rename command batch script rename only first file but it also remove extension... Thanks in advance...

Comment: It would help us answer your question if you could provide the exact commands you ran and what the filenames looked like before and after.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried many methods (using Windows Explorer, the Command Prompt, PowerShell, or using Multi Commander File Manager).

If you don’t want to install a third party utility, then check [this helpful article](https://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/).

But if you're ok with a third party utility, I found that using [Multi Commander](http://multicommander.com/downloads) file manager was the easiest and fastest way to solve the issue.

Now open MC, go to Extensions > Multi-Rename, a window will open where you can choose whether to replace the file name with the extension, or just the file name, or just the extension, along with other options.

Note: you might get a message telling you that the renaming has failed. Ignore it, close the multi-rename window, and go check the files. They should be renamed.